# What is the "bash man page" or "bash manual page" and where can I find it?

Tags: bash, manual

What is the "bash man page" or "bash manual page" and where can I find it?

Does this just mean the stuff that comes up when you do:

```
command --help
```

Will that always work?

Comment: It's usually `man command` (`man bash` for instance). It's _usually_ installed, but some stripped down servers don't have mandb/manpages

Comment: The "bash man page" is the man page **for bash itself**, not for commands outside of / not built into bash.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an excellent GNU bash reference :
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

In general you can do `man bash` to see the exact man page for your version of bash.

Answer (score 1):

Type `man bash` for the man(ual) page or, more usefully, `info bash` for the full manual.